# What are 2-cells (and their horizontal compositions) in the bicategory of spans?

Tags: category-theory

According to [this](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/09/06/monads-monoids-and-categories/) blog and [this](https://graphicallinearalgebra.net/2017/04/16/a-monoid-is-a-category-a-category-is-a-monad-a-monad-is-a-monoid/) blog, a 2-cell in Span(C), i.e. a morphism between spans, is a morphism between the two apices such that the 2 triangles commute. Also, horizontal composition of spans is a pullback but what about horizontal composition of 2-cells? its not defined and i can't think of a way to naturally define some morphsim between two pullbacks. I also couldnt find a definition in MacLane's 'Categories for the working mathematician' or nlab. I found a definition [here](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/span2C.pdf) - but their definition of 2-cells seems completely different than in the blogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose given four spans and some morphisms between them:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
A@<<<B@>>>C@<<<D@>>>E\\
@VV{\mathrm{id}}V@VVV @VV{\mathrm{id}}V @VVV @VV{\mathrm{id}}V\\
A@<<<B'@>>>C@<<<D'@>>>E
\end{CD}$$
We must define a map $B\times_C D\to B'\times_C D'$ satisyfing some conditions. But the universal property of the pushout guarantees that the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
B@>>>C@<<<D\\
@VVV @VV{\mathrm{id}}V @VVV\\
B'@>>>C@<<<D'
\end{CD}$$
induces exactly such a map $B\times_C D\to B'\times_C D'$, such that e.g. the diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
B\times_C D@>>> B'\times_C D'\\
@VV{\mathrm{proj}}V @VV{\mathrm{proj}}V\\
B @>>> B'
\end{CD}$$
commutes (and similarly for $C$ and the pair $(D,D')$). This allows you to see that our map $B\times_C D\to B'\times_C D'$ indeed satisfies the necessary conditions to be a $2$-morphism between horizontal compositions of spans.

It's by the way true that there is not a single definition of a span category, so it is always good to look up how an author defines it.